# Automatically invoke xprop at a named point on the desktop (X11, Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, x11, xdotool

```
 xprop | grep WM_CLASS\(STRING\)
```

After typing that into a terminal, I have to click onto a window to get a result.

I want to automatize this. I'd like to get the WM_NAME-Window name at a named position, say, x=10 and y=40 (BFB).

```
xprop | grep WM_NAME\(STRING\) 
sleep(1)
xdotool mousemove 10 40 click 1
```

Each command on its own is working, but not all together. How can I put this into a script that executes all commands?

Comment: Wny not use the window ID or name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that xprop is blocking for the mouse click so it needs to be done in the background.  The `wait` is not strictly necessary, but makes the script exit more cleanly by waiting for `xprop` to complete.

```
#!/bin/bash
xprop | grep WM_NAME\(STRING\) &
pid=!$
sleep 1
xdotool mousemove 10 40 click 1
wait $pid
```

Comment: Hm, it would also be good to reset the mouse to its previous position. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Try xdotool mousemove 10 40 click 1 mousemove restore

Answer (score 0):

To get that in python code, if someone else is interested:

```
import subprocess as s

p=s.Popen(["xprop", "WM_NAME"], stdout=s.PIPE)
r=s.Popen(["xdotool", "mousemove", "10", "40", "click", "1", "mousemove", "restore"], stdout=s.PIPE)

out, err = p.communicate()
print(out)
```

If you want to adjust the output slightly, type "WM_CLASS".